# Is it correct to use to begin with to begin a speech?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Perhaps, I've been misunderstood about the concept of **to begin with**. I've been enlightened by the book I've been learning that the phrase I've mentioned above is used to introduce a sequence.

Since the translation (into my native language) seems to have a little resemblance to opening remarks. Is it OK if I use that phrase to (for example) start a speech?

For instance:

> To begin with, I would like to say thank you very much to each and
> every one of you for willingly being here with us today.

Comment: Yes you can.  There are better ways of saying the same thing, for example, "I would first like to say thank you..." and there are many , many better ways to start a speech.

Comment: When writing (or speech writing), you start with an introduction or overview of your topic, and then if desired you go into detail. The best use of 'to begin with' is probably when you move to the detail section of your speech. As an example, your speech might go: 'Thank you all for coming. I would like to explain why I think every citizen should volunteer their time to pick up trash in public spaces. To begin with, this will beautify our parks. It will also reduce tripping hazards on sidewalks.'